# how to clear a text edit field? android python appium

Tags: android, python, appium

how to clear text edit field? android python appium? 
I tried that way:

```
  el = driver.find_element_by_id('text edit field id').clear()
  el.click()
  el.clear()
```

however, it actually deletes only one symbol.

I think may by call an el.click() twice and send keycode to delete highlighted text area but how to highlight the text?

Interestingly, such problem reproduces in Sony Xperia z3 compact, android 5.0.1.
In lg, nexus android 4.4,5.1 accordingly, the above code works well

Comment: Why are you highlighting the text to clear it? Just get the ID/name/xpath of the field and user clear() method. It should be good.

Comment: in Sony Xperia z3 compact clear() doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had faced same issue with my android application but i am doing automation in  java , so for the solution i am performing tap Action twice near the location of the element so it will select all the text which already written in text field and after that click on that "cut" symbol so it will clear text field.
i have written a method for sendkeys in android device.

```
     public void typeForAndroid(AppiumDriver appiumDriver,WebElement ele,String text)
{
    if(ele.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        ele.sendKeys(text);
    }
    else
    {
    TouchAction action=new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
    action.tap(ele.getLocation().getX()+5, ele.getLocation().getY()+5);
    action.tap(ele.getLocation().getX()+5, ele.getLocation().getY()+5);

    appiumDriver.performTouchAction(action);
    pause(2);
    try{
        appiumDriver.findElementById("android:id/cut").click();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         appiumDriver.sendKeyEvent(67);
     }

      pause(2);
    ele.sendKeys(text);
    }
}
```

this is working for me. I hope this might works for you.
in this i have used appiumdriver but you can also use androiddriver.
Thanks

Comment: there's no a method "getLocation().getX()" in python appium